# What is the most recent stash in Git, zero index or the biggest index?

Tags: git, git-stash

I have several items in stash. How can I know which one is the most recent? I need to apply the most resent changes back.

```sh
$ git stash list
stash@{0}: WIP on MD-1098: 96e121d8 MD-1098
stash@{1}: WIP on MD-1098: 0aaa2ae5 MD-1098
stash@{2}: WIP on MD-1098: 04c86108 MD-1098
```

Comment: You don't need to specify *anything* to pop or apply the most recent one, but it's 0. See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing

Answer (score 4):

Stash Index zero (0) is the latest.

Stashes start with index 0 (as the first stash) and then they are shifted by one on every stash add. So always the new stash is index 0 and the rest are incremented by one